# paypal payment takes 15 to 20 seconds in execution Is it's normal time?

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have added PayPal payment on my website with **Create payment using a saved credit card** i have test on cURL and SDK both, requests give me response in 15-20 sec. Is it's normal time?

**curl code**

```
$accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$credit_card = "CARD-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$amt = 5;
$currency = "USD";
$description = "testing time";

$str = "{\n    \"intent\": \"sale\",\n    \"payer\": {\n      \"payment_method\": \"credit_card\",\n      \"funding_instruments\":[\n        {\n          \"credit_card_token\": {\n            \"credit_card_id\": \"$credit_card\"\n          }\n        }\n      ]\n    },\n    \"transactions\":[\n      {\n        \"amount\":{\n          \"total\": \"$amt\",\n          \"currency\": \"$currency\"\n        },\n        \"description\": \"$description\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$accessToken;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

**SDK**

sdk example code -> 
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingSavedCard.html

Comment: nope, it's not normal. PS, for curl, `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');` would make it faster (will now use a compressed transfer encoding. usually gzip/deflate)

Comment: @hanshenrik no difference in response time with curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip,deflate');

Comment: Is it a live account test account? - I've noticed that test account seems to work slower

Comment: Generally, if you are using a really overused credit card, it might take a while. Try creating a new credit card using http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/ or any other similar services.